# JSON to CSV using Python

Tags: python, json, csv

been playing with Python recently and whilst has a lot of success, one thing is driving me nuts - how Python handles JSON!

I'm trying to output this into a CSV and for simple JSON (without multiple objects) it's all fine, but with the below example I just can't get it to work. I get errors all over the place either key errors or dict vs string errors - and then they differ even more when trying to write to csv either using csv writer or pandas.
So I'm deliberately avoiding pasting all my attempts in an attempt to see if there is a standard way to approach this without influencing a direction which I've been historically trying to take :)

JSON Example (response from a URL) using response = requests.get(url)

```
{
  "body": {
    "stores": [
      {
        "id": "1002",
        "groupId": "aberdeen",
        "displayName": "Aberdeen",
        "link": "/store/aberdeen",
        "address": "123, TheRoad, A24 8EN, Aberdeen",
        "Url": "https://web.co.uk",
        "other": false,
        "other1": null
      },
      {
        "id": "1234",
        "groupId": "Basingstoke",
        "displayName": "Basingstoke",
        "link": "/store/Basingstoke",
        "address": "Union Square, The Square, BA11 5RG, Basingstoke",
        "Url": "https://web.co.uk",
        "other": false,
        "other1": null
      },...
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this?
Ideally I'd like a CSV export as below:

ID, GroupID, DisplayName

8014, aberdeen, Aberdeen

8018, Basingstoke, Basingstoke

...

Thanks
Immy

Comment: You've done a good job explaining what you want to do.  Now include the code you've written so far and what it outputs, so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(d['body']['stores']).to_csv('my_file.csv')
```

Comment: Conner you legend! I can't believe it's just a line of code - I've spent hours trying multiple approaches. Thanks. btw, can't vote up - new account. Sorry.

Comment: @ImtiazUllah you should be able to use the checkmark beneath upvoting to accept an answer